# sort data.frame by column alphabetically in dplyr without converting to factor

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, dplyr

I'm working with data using `dplyr` package and need to sort a `data.frame` by one of the columns alphabetically. Problem is that this column is `character` and `dplyr` arranges my `data.frame` in wrong manner.
Here's the example.

```
require("dplyr")
set.seed(7)
df1 <- data.frame(name = sample(c("A", "a", "b", "B"), 20, T), 
                  value = rnorm(20), stringsAsFactors = F)
str(df1)
# 'data.frame':  20 obs. of  2 variables:
#      $ name : chr  "B" "a" "A" "A" ...
#      $ value: num  0.357 2.717 2.281 0.324 1.896 ...
df1 %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(val = sum(value))
# Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
# 
#   name       val
# 1    A 5.4297509
# 2    B 0.8402506
# 3    a 3.8079681
# 4    b 0.7522799
```

Here in column `name` first go CAPITALS and then small letters. `arrange` doesn't change anything. If we make `name` variable a `factor` then it becomes arranged in right order. That's it

```
set.seed(7)
df2 <- data.frame(name = sample(c("A", "a", "b", "B"), 20, T), 
                  value = rnorm(20), stringsAsFactors = T)
df2 %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(val = sum(value))
# Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
# 
#   name       val
# 1    a 3.8079681
# 2    A 5.4297509
# 3    b 0.7522799
# 4    B 0.8402506
```

In my data processing I'd like to keep `name` of `character` type, and breaking `%>%`-pipes of `dplyr` code with another code isn't nice too, so, is it possible with `dplyr` to sort the first `df1` as `df2` ?

Comment: I guess the first output is the correct order?

Comment: I wish the output like in `df2` but my data is `df1`

Comment: I am not sure the problem in creating a factor variable by specifying the levels.  `df1 %>% group_by(name=factor(name, levels=c('a','A', 'b', 'B'))) %>% summarise(val=sum(value))` and then you may change it to character.  Otherwise, you may need another identifier or so

Comment: You may also try `match`. ie. `Un1 <- sort(unique(toupper(df1$name)));  df1 %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(val=sum(value)) %>% arrange(match(name, c(rbind(tolower(Un1),Un1))))`

Comment: `arrange(df1, tolower(name), name)`